# Como puedo insertar registros a una tabla con datos de la misma tabla sql

Tags: sql

Como puedo obtener de una tabla de transacciones mis lotes anteriores a mi transacción actual pero solo los que tengan cantidad final diferente a cero e insertarlos después de mi transacción actual

Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla donde hay dos movimientos de tipo inicial y cinco de tipo transacción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy buscando es que me quede de la siguiente manera, como pueden ver cada que A1 tiene una transacción, se muestra que el A2 sigue vigente con cantidad por 359, después cuando tengo una transacción de A3 solo me muestra que tengo A2 por 359 pero ya no me muestra A1 porque ya quedó en cantidad final cero, lo mismo pasa cuando al final tengo un movimiento de A2 solo me muestra que mi lote vigente es A3 ya que A1 quedó en cero desde dos transacciones atrás

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! MAs alla que no especificaste ninguna base de datos, eso no parece SQL ni por asomo... esa forma de mostrar los datos no es logica... que estas tratando de solucionar?

Comment: EL requerimiento del cliente es así de extraño, en resumen es un historial de transacciones de inventario donde por cada transacción que realices de un producto el quiere ver los lotes que aun tiene disponibles del mismo producto, las capturas son de un ejemplo que pase a Excel es por eso que no parece sql

Comment: Y no vas a poder en sql hacer eso.. lo tiene que resover tu vista me parece... SQL procesa los registros de a uno... no va para atras y adelante mirando que paso...

Comment: Y parte de tu trabajo es guiar al cliente para que no pida cosas ilogicas... o guiarlo a cosas que le sirvan mucho mas!!!

Comment: Después de muchos intentos voy a realizarlo mediante c# antes de mostrar la información en pdf, créeme que tratamos de convencerlo de obtener esa información mediante otros informes, que este solo es un historial de transacciones no de totales de inventario pero nos dicen que es un informe que solicita la entidad financiera administrativa de su país (SUNAT en Perú) y pues que podemos hacer ante eso. De cualquier forma gracias, ya que soy nuevo no se que procede con este post, se elimina, se cierra, se espera una solución?

Comment: dudo que encuentres una solucion en sql para algo que claramente no es un problema de sql.. pero hace como gustes...